# Running android emulator in a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, android, emulator

I would like to run the Android emulator on Linux which is opened through a virtual machine using VirtualBox. I tried to give the Linux machine more RAM and video memory but nothing seems to be working and the emulator is genuinely slow! Any advice on what could I do to make it become faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualbox does **not** support full 3D Acceleration for Windows, let alone Linux. It may be worth your while to just get [VMWare Player](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/).